# Ruby Freezes when Installing on server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, nginx, capistrano

I have a Digital Ocean account, and i've never had this problem before.  But whenever I try to use cap deploy:install, to install ruby and etc to the server.  The command prompt get's to the point in the first image.  ("Installing Ruby") and then  If I cancel it, it will it will show image 2.  If anyone could help with this.  That would be amazing.  It's for a client of mine and I can't seem to figure it out.

Image = Ubuntu 1 Gig
Nginx

[image]

[image]

Comment: How long do you wait before you try to cancel it?

Comment: I left it up all day.  Several Hours.  Never had this issue in the past. It generally would take, max half an hour in the past. I even tried making the image bigger but that didn't help either.

Comment: That is strange.  Does it work when run directly on the command-line?